# Replacing terms in a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string containing, among other items, a whole bunch of "RSPXXXX" where X is a number ranging from 0-9. Now I want to replace RSPXXXX with 'RSPXXXX'. But am having a hard time replacing adding the final '. That is, it's easy to tack on a ' in front of R, but I can't figure out how to add another one on the end. Do I have to use a for or if loop?

Any other ideas? I attached a sample code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Store2{
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader b1 =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Reactions.csv"));
        BufferedWriter b2 =
            new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Store2.txt"));
        String strRead; String strWrite;
        while ((strRead=b1.readLine())!=null){
            String splitarray[] = strRead.split("\t");
            String reactions = splitarray[0];
            String genes = splitarray[7];
            b2.write("v.fx('");
            b2.write(reactions);
            b2.write("')$(");
            b2.write(genes.replace("R","'R"));
            b2.write(")=0;");
            b2.newLine();
        }
        b2.close();
    } //main()
}
```

Comment: I should also make clear: there's more in the "genes" string than just these RSPXXXX terms. So I can't just do a b2.write(genes);b2.write("'");

Comment: seems like the format it pretty consistant, starts with RSP then 4 numbers. You should be able to leverage regular expression to identify the whole string you want to wrap around and then replace it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
b2.write(genes.replaceAll("RSP\\d+", "'$0'"));
```

Comment: Maybe `RSP\\d{4}` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Both d{4} and d+ lead to a "cannot find symbol" error, both with and without quotes. Any ideas?

Comment: @kbball Did you include the double backslash prior to the `d`? Eg. `\\d` ?

Comment: This works for me: https://gist.github.com/perses/5750603. It produces: 'RSP1234' 'RSP5678'.

Comment: Actually I think I missed that. Now, however, I am error free but my output looks unchanged.

Comment: Try to print out genes. What does it look like?

Comment: It looks like this: Gene AssociationRSP_0723RSP_0723RSP_1012 | RSP_4032RSP_1849RSP_0147 | RSP_2319 | RSP_0375 | RSP_0377 | RSP_1568RSP_0763 | RSP_3439 (RSP_1146 & RSP_1149) | (RSP_1146 & RSP_0189) etc. etc.

Comment: The HelloWorld file worked for me as well but that code doesn't seem to work when I use it in my document

Comment: Ohhhh now I get it. It's the _ that was throwing me off

Comment: Now it's working. Sorry, I guess I phrased the question wrong! Thanks for your help everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
b2.write((genes.substring(0, 7) + "'" + genes.substring(7)).replace("R", "'R"));
```

A somewhat clearer way, though, would be to create a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` and perform the string changes inside it:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("'").append(genes).insert(7, "'");
b2.write(sb.toString());
```